# Find any repeating css classnames and add additional classname to each first-child

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Sounds kinda silly. Let’s say I have a code like this but i don’t know the class names because they are user generated in wordpress.

```
<ul>
<li class="A"></li>
<li class="A"></li>
<li class="A"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
```

and I need to habe this:

```
<ul>
<li class="A first"></li>
<li class="A"></li>
<li class="A"></li>
<li class="bla first"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="bla"></li>
<li class="foo first"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
<li class="foo"></li>
```

is there any way/idea to handle this in javascript or php?

the specific wordpress loop looks like this:

```
    <?php
        add_filter('posts_orderby','raufrunter');
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'preistraeger',
            'meta_key' => 'wpcf-preiskategorie',
            'meta_query'  => array( array( 'key' => 'wpcf-preiskategorie', ), array( 'key' => 'wpcf-sortiername', )  )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        remove_filter('posts_orderby','raufrunter');
    ?>

    <?php
        $preisclass = types_render_field( "preiskategorie", array() );
        $faul = array(" ", ".", "ä", "ü", "ö");
        $preisclass = str_replace($faul, "", $preisclass);
    ?>

    <!-- here I need the extra classnam if it’s repeating itself. -->
    <span class="li <?php echo $preisclass;?>"> 
        <h6><?php echo types_render_field( "preiskategorie", array( ) );?></h6>
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a>' ); ?>
    </span>

    <?php 
        endwhile; 
    ?>
```

Comment: define an empty array before the while loop, before the span check if class is already in array, if not, add "first" to class and add class to array.

Comment: thanks. sounds logic, but i don’t know how to do this.

Comment: Tell me you at least tried, please

Comment: I wrote the php not by myself. I was more like playing lego. I even had to google how to create an empty array. so …

Comment: That is a good first step. Now that you know how to define an empty array search for `in_array` and how to add an element to an array. After that you are all set. Or you could use one of the answers below, they let you display your wrong classes first and then adjust them with script.

Comment: Thanks @RST. I very appreciate your purpose, but I wasn’t looking for a lesson, I was looking for a ready-made solution. So I took @KevBot’s Code. I think the way over php would be a little sexier and produces less traffic, but I had to hurry.

Comment: That is the problem, Stackoverflow is not a coding service. It is a website to help people improve/understand/fix their code so they know what to do next time. You are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach an identifier to the `ul`, you could use JS to do it like this:

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul.user-list');

Array.from(ul.querySelectorAll('li'))
  .map(element => element.className.split(/\s+/))
  .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
  .filter((elem, pos, arr) => arr.indexOf(elem) == pos)
  .forEach(className => ul.querySelector('li.' + className).classList.add('first'));
```

```css
.A,
.bla,
.foo {
  color: lightcoral;
}
.A.first,
.bla.first,
.foo.first {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="user-list">
  <li class="A">A 1</li>
  <li class="A">A 2</li>
  <li class="A">A 3</li>
  <li class="bla">bla 1</li>
  <li class="bla">bla 2</li>
  <li class="bla">bla 3</li>
  <li class="bla">bla 4</li>
  <li class="foo">foo 1</li>
  <li class="foo">foo 2</li>
  <li class="foo">foo 3</li>
  <li class="foo">foo 4</li>
  <li class="foo">foo 5</li>
</ul>
```

---

### ES5 Version

If you are not using es6, here is the es5 equivalent of the JavaScript code:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul.user-list');

[].slice.call(ul.querySelectorAll('li'))
    .map(function (element) {
        return element.className.split(/\s+/);
    })
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    })
    .filter(function (elem, pos, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    })
    .forEach(function (className) {
        ul.querySelector('li.' + className).classList.add('first');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much KevBot. Your "ES6-Version" worked perfect for my need. To be honest, I don’t even know if I’m using ES6 or 5. But if 6 works, it works, right?

Comment: @jwssnr If you're not using a transpiler for your JavaScript (it sounds like you're not), then you should use the ES5 version. Some browsers to not fully support es6 yet (hence the need to the transpiler, like babel). So, to be safe, it sounds like you should to with the ES5 version.

Comment: Okay. I’ll switch to ES5. Crossbrowsertesting tomorrow.
 Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Oooh! Strange behaviour. It works realy fine but not o one class. On line 243 of http://aufbau.kulturstiftung.sg/alphabet/ Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sort(){

  var arr = [];
  $("ul").children("li").each(function(){
    liClass = $(this).attr("class");
    inarray = $.inArray(liClass, arr)
    if (inarray == -1){
        $(this).addClass("first");
        arr.push(liClass);
    }
  });
  
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="A">33</li>
<li class="A">22</li>
<li class="A">11</li>
<li class="bla">22</li>
<li class="bla">33</li>
<li class="bla">44</li>
<li class="bla">55</li>
<li class="foo">66</li>
<li class="foo">33</li>
<li class="foo">66</li>
<li class="foo">55</li>
<li class="foo">11</li>
</ul>

<button onClick="sort()">sort</button>
```

Here you go